# Brainstorming Community Promotion Ad Ideas

Tags: discussion, design

Hopefully everyone has read the [Community Promotion Ads](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/community-promotion-ads-2014) already. In order to give us a chance to discuss potential ideas, I figured I would toss this here to allow people to discuss their ideas so that we can expand and improve on them before tossing together the ad (also to collaborate on design if people want to do that).

If you have an idea for an ad, please give a general outline such as:

### Who

Who will the ad be targeted at?

### Where

Where will the ad point those people to?

### Why

Why will this ad will benefit our community?

Answer (score 4):

### Who

People who are just starting out their careers who browse here from a search engine.

### What

Point them to a meta-post containing a list of questions that go over the basics for someone looking for a first time job such as:

1. [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)
2. [How can I ask my interviewers for feedback following an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/662/how-can-i-ask-my-interviewers-for-feedback-following-an-interview)
3. [In an interview, is it required to have question(s) for the interviewer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/in-an-interview-is-it-required-to-have-questions-for-the-interviewer)
4. [How important is a grade point average on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/209/how-important-is-a-grade-point-average-on-a-resume)
5. etc.

(these are just examples, I'm sure there are better questions out there for this, and if not, we should brush up the ones we have, and possibly create the ones we don't)

### Why

New employees will find us from Google when looking for an answer to some of these basic questions. If we create an ad that they see that points them to other helpful content, we have a better chance of having them get involved with the community rather than just getting their answer and moving on.

It may also get us good content from new hires which will help us improve our content as a resource for future job seekers.

#### Sample Ad

[image: First Job Ad]

Comment: This is a great idea; it would act an introduction to the site and may also help with SEO if external entities link to it as a resource. So instead of a meta post, I'd strongly suggest creating the post on the main site. It would actually be a rare, real, *legitimate* use of community wiki. It would be a table of contents of sorts, and it would keep meta for what it's intended, for discussions *about* Workplace SE. If you create the post, flag it and I'll CW it.

Comment: @jmort, my issue is finding good questions that would fit the bill and compile a bunch of our better questions. A lot of them are from before I joined, so I could really use some help from the community. I will draft up what I can when I get some time, but I hope the rest of the community will pitch in too.

Comment: Those first 4 are possibly a good start. In fact, many times less is more. Put too many links on the page, and the content becomes diluted.

Comment: @jmort created and flagged [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20323/what-should-i-know-when-applying-for-my-first-job/20324#20324).

Comment: I agree something like this might be useful, but wouldn't it be best to have it on meta? It seems very meta, especially as most of it is just links to other answers, and that way people wont get confused about why that question is acceptable but theirs is not

Answer (score 3):

### Who

Regular members who don't participate in community moderation

### What

A landing page (meta post?) for folks starting to moderate including:

1. Links to privilege levels
2. Links to the help center/FAQ on each privilege you can have
3. Links to the review queues

### Why

Post-graduation, we have lost a lot of ability to self-moderate. By teaching people the ropes, we can hopefully get some people who aren't moderating regularly to hop back in, and folks who are interested in learning our moderation style to read up on it and hop in when they hit the right privilege.

#### Sample Ad

[image: We Want You Robot Ad]